# How to pass value from Button.setOnClickListener to onDateSet Android

Tags: java, android

I have a class called `InboxActivity` in which I use datepicker, and I need to pass some data(it is one string var, like this: String test = "aa";) from

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);



        btn_outbox = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_outbox);
        btn_outbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    **FROM HERE!!!!**

            }
        });
```

to here:

```
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


        public int Syear;
        public int Smonth;
        @Override

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: So users can help you; please edit your question and specify what data you wish to transfer and maybe an idea of your expected end result as this question is too vague.

Comment: I need to pass one string

Comment: You can just make a member variable assign it on onclick and use that inside your DatePickerDIalog :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to test it real quick, but I am pretty sure if you implement OnClickListener's interface to your class, and then override onClick(), you can use private variables inside of your class to do what you want.

```
public class InboxActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    ....
```

Then this inside of your activity

```
private String data;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ....
    btn_outbox.setOnClickListener(this);

    ....
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

        public int Syear;
        public int Smonth;

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // Do what you need to, data string works here

        }

    };
}


onClick(View v){
    data = "some string";
}
```

Comment: But can i use this variable data in the onDateSet ?

Comment: Should. I will test it real quick.